# Define gradle task, to run task with specific system properties

Tags: selenium, gradle

I am struggling to create a gradle task to execute the test task with specified system.properties that I use for my Selenium Tests

```
task firefox() << {
    System.setProperty('driver', 'firefox')
    tasks.clean.execute()
    tasks.test.execute()
}
```

That does not work obviously. I highly appreciate any help, to finalize my built script!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Task.execute()` should never be called from a build script (bad things can happen if you do). It's up to Gradle to call this method. The way to set system properties for the `test` task is:

```
test {
    systemProperty "driver", "firefox"
}
```

`System.setProperty()` won't have any effect because tests always execute in a separate JVM.

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for the quick reply! This answers my question partially. From the command-line point of view I would like to call sth. like: "gradle firefox" or "gradle phantomjs". If it is bad style to call the execute function, how can I set up a task that invokes the test task including the property set in another task?

Comment: It seems that the only possible solution is a variable that I pass via the commandline -Pvar=firefox and set the property: systemProperty "driver", var

Comment: There is no straightforward way to do that. Instead, you can add two test tasks, or you can pass in some system (or project) property and configure the test task based on that. If that isn't good enough, more complicated alternatives are to use an embedded build (`GradleBuild` task) or to manipulate `gradle.startParameter.taskNames`.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the advice. I made two test tasks and it works like a charm ;)